# if a react component re-render does it mean all the code in that component re-run?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having difficulty trying to understand react re-rendering. if a state change occurs and re-rendering is schedule does rerender occur only after all code of that component is run?

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      result:[],
      isLoading:true,
      isActive:"",
      currentPage:1,
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Child1/>
                <Child2 name={this.isActive}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child2 extends PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    getResult = async(query='pasta')=>{
        console.log("this log loop finitely")
        this.setState({
            property1: newValue
          })
    }
    render(){
        this.getRecipe('pizza');
        return(
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I notice that the console.log hit an infinite loop

Comment: Can you add your code-snippet, that will help to understand the problem in details

Comment: only render method will execute on re-render

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `this.setState()` in your render function. Every change to the `state` causes a re-render, and that it what puts your component in an infinite loop.
You might consider moving your state change to `componentDidUpdate` or other more appropriate lifecycle mthod.

Comment: if i use componentDidUpdate, is this.setState() the only way to bring up the data, say i have a function on componentDidUpdate that return a value, how to i get the value out of componentDidUpdate?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but you can call `setState` right in `componentDidUpdate`. Just make sure you do it inside an `if` clause so it doesn't cause infinite loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `render()` method is executed after each state change, the constructor is only executed when a component mounts.
See the [component lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)